# How can I know what auto-increment values were created for a batch update using JDBC?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc

I think the question sums it up well enough, here's my code at the moment but it's not giving me the required results. I want to return an int array containing the generated auto-increment id's for each row created in that batch.

```
CREATE_APPOINTMENT = database.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_APPOINTMENTS + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

   public static int[] createAppointment(Appointment... appointments) {
    int[] ids = new int[appointments.length];
    int count = 0;
    try {
        for (Appointment a : appointments) {
            CREATE_APPOINTMENT.setDate(2, a.date);
            CREATE_APPOINTMENT.setTime(3, a.time);
            CREATE_APPOINTMENT.setInt(4, a.duration);
            CREATE_APPOINTMENT.setString(5, a.clientName);
            CREATE_APPOINTMENT.addBatch();
        }
        CREATE_APPOINTMENT.executeBatch();

        ResultSet resultSet = CREATE_APPOINTMENT.getGeneratedKeys();
        if (resultSet != null)
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                ids[count++] = resultSet.getInt(1);
            }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
    return ids;
}
```

I've tried creating 8 appointments and their id's are created successfully according to the database but my returns array only contains the last id and the rest are zeros. Where am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it is impossible. ***stmt.getGeneratedKeys()*** will always return only one value because this method in sqlite-jdbc driver is implemented so:

```
    ResultSet getGeneratedKeys() throws SQLException {
            if (getGeneratedKeys == null)
                getGeneratedKeys = conn.prepareStatement("select last_insert_rowid();");
            return getGeneratedKeys.executeQuery();
        }
```

Your array is initialized with zero values, and then the last generated id is assigned to the first element of array.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change preparing statement like this:

```
CREATE_APPOINTMENT = database.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_APPOINTMENTS + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

Comment: That sadly did not change anything.

Comment: Yes, see my explanation below.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the [JDBC Specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr221/index.html) section 13.6: Retrieving Auto Generated Values provides information on how to do this:

```
String keyColumn[] = {"ORDER_ID"};
...
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
int rows = stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO ORDERS " +
"(ISBN, CUSTOMERID) " +
"VALUES (966431502, ’BILLG’)",
keyColumn);
ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
```

Two paragraphs after this example the specification says:

> It is implementation-defined as to whether getGeneratedKeys will
>   return generated values after invoking the executeBatch method.

So, I guess you can test your driver and see if it supports it.

Comment: If it doesn't, you can always execute the query `SELECT last_insert_rowid()`.

Comment: @CL Wouldn't that return the row id for the last insert only? I think the question is about batch inserts. Also, even in a single insert scenario, I think it work only if the the isolation level guarantees that you will see only your own last insert.

Comment: Yes, when using batches, you need support in the JDBC driver.

Comment: For rows inserted with id's generated 1 - 8, the int array returned contains [8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0].